# Mercury bulb on spirit thermometer?

Tags: equipment, mercury

I recently broke a Quickfit distillation thermometer and the bulb had liquid metal in it. I assumed it's mercury and acted accordingly. However, the column looks like spirit filled (blue liquid). Has anyone seen those, and if so, do you know if the metal is indeed mercury or something else? The model is Quickfit MF 31/2 (not MF 31/2S which is the newer one). I have never seen mercury and spirit combined in other thermometers. Just curious that's all.

[image: Thermometer image]

Comment: One of the thermometer's designs than would use both mercury and ethanol is a [Six's thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six%27s_thermometer). Also, a photo might help.

Comment: Added a photo. This is of another one we have. The bulb is definitely metal filled, but not the column.

Comment: Look closely at the tube at the different angles. Many thermometers these days use mercury or galinstan and the *colored (painted) line* along the inner side of the tube that makes the metal appear colored, blue in this case (see e.g. [this image](https://www.sciencesource.com/Doc/TR1_WATERMARKED/6/e/8/e/SS2387015.jpg?d63642067667)).

Comment: It may just be a blue dye deposited on the back of the tube